# Why does the Schwarz Christoffel Transform have three independent parameters?

Tags: complex-analysis, geometry

Why is the Schwarz Christoffel Transformation for the half plane uniquely determined up to an arbitrary choice of three prevertices? Is there a simple intuitive way to motivate this, rather than resorting to the properties of Moebius transforms as I have seen in the literature?

Comment: Would you consider the [Riemann mapping theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_mapping_theorem) a “simple and intuitive” motivation?

Comment: I think it would depend how it was explained. I definitely wouldn't discriminate against a good answer!